# Regular Expression Matching C#

Tags: .net, regex

I need to match the following regular expression

```
lines...
# TYPE word expression
lines...
```

where expression can be only one of the following summary, counter, gauge, histogram or untyped

For example:

```
# HELP http_requests A summary of all the requests being made
# TYPE http_requests summary
http_request{requestMethod="GET",requestPath="/status/detailed",requestStatusCode="503"} 824
http_request{requestMethod="GET",requestPath="/status/detailed",requestStatusCode="503"} 334
```

I tried the following but it seems to not be working

```
?^{# TYPE}\s\w\s(summary|counter|gauge|histogram|untyped)$?
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Add the data you are working with too.

Comment: @Stuart i added an example

Comment: Try `(?m)^# TYPE +\w+ +(summary|counter|gauge|histogram|untyped)\r?$` if  you need to match the whole line in a multiline string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, it worked like a charm

Comment: @Keyko I posted an answer with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?m)^# TYPE +\w+ +(summary|counter|gauge|histogram|untyped)\r?$
```

That is what you need to match lines in a multiline string.

Details

- `(?m)` - multiline modifier
- `^` - start of a line
- `# TYPE +` - `# TYPE` substring and one or more spaces
- `\w+ +` - 1+ word chars and then 1+ spaces
- `(summary|counter|gauge|histogram|untyped)` - one of the substrings in the alternation group
- `\r?` - an optional CR symbol (necessary as `$` does not match before this symbol in .NET regex)
- `$` - end of a line.

Comment: Just FYI: if there are tabs or hard spaces between words replace the `SPACE+` pattern with `[\p{Zs}\t]+`.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully tested with: **# TYPE (.*)\b(summary|counter|gauge|histogram|untyped)\b\r?\n?**

This works if you match against the whole example (multiple lines of text), but if you iterate through every line and match against the regex use:

**^# TYPE (.*)\b(summary|counter|gauge|histogram|untyped)\b\r?\n?$**